# Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN,NaNLNaN,NaN"

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm tring to create a multi-line chart using D3.js v4. I'm using this example: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955.

Sample csv Data:

```
storageSystem,poolId,availableVolumeCapacity,date
system01,0,18031398,20170413
system01,1,15626268,20170413
system01,2,61256286,20170413
system01,3,119514990,20170413
system02,0,15046668,20170413
system02,1,12486558,20170413
system02,2,12303396,20170413
system03,0,35171335,20170413
system03,1,17263722,20170413
system01,0,18031387,20170414
system01,1,15626257,20170414
system01,2,61256275,20170414
system01,3,119514989,20170414
system02,0,15046657,20170414
system02,1,12486547,20170414
system02,2,12303385,20170414
system03,0,35171324,20170414
system03,1,17263711,20170414
```

Data Object:

```
0: Object
  color: "#8c564b"
  key: "system03"
  values: Array(2)
    0: Object
      key: "0"
      values: Array(23)
        0: Object
          availableVolumeCapacity: 35171335
          date: Thu Apr 13 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
          poolId: "0"
          storageSystem: "system03"
    1: Object
      key: "1"
      values: Array(23)
        0: Object
          availableVolumeCapacity: 17263722
          date: Thu Apr 13 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
          poolId:"1"
          storageSystem: "system03"
```

D3.js Code:

```
var svg = d3.select("svg")
    m = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 50, left: 20},
    w = svg.attr("width") - m.left - m.right,
    h = svg.attr("height") - m.top - m.bottom,
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + m.left + "," + m.top + ")");

var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y%m%d");

var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, w]),
    y = d3.scaleLinear().range([h, 0]),
    z = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

var line = d3.line()
    .curve(d3.curveBasis)
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.availableVolumeCapacity); });

d3.csv("ssystem.csv", function(error, data) {
    if (error) throw error;
    data.forEach(function(d) {
            d.date = parseTime(d.date);
            d.availableVolumeCapacity = +d.availableVolumeCapacity;
});

x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.availableVolumeCapacity; })]);

var dataNest = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) {return d.storageSystem; })
    .key(function(d) {return d.poolId; })
    .entries(data);

console.log(dataNest)

legendSpace = w/dataNest.length;

dataNest.forEach(function(d,i) {
    svg.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .style("stroke", function() {
            return d.color = z(d.key); })
        .attr("id", 'tag'+d.key.replace(/\s+/g, ''))
        .attr("d", line(d.values));
    svg.append("text")
        .attr("x", (legendSpace/2)+i*legendSpace)
        .attr("y", h + (m.bottom/2)+ 5)
        .attr("class", "legend")
        .style("fill", function() {
            return d.color = z(d.key); })
        .on("click", function(){
            // Determine if current line is visible
            var active = d.active ? false : true,
            newOpacity = active ? 0 : 1;
            // Hide or show the elements based on the ID
            d3.select("#tag"+d.key.replace(/\s+/g, ''))
                .transition().duration(100)
                .style("opacity", newOpacity);
            // Update whether or not the elements are active
            d.active = active;
            })
        .text(d.key);
});

svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + h + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", "0.71em")
      .attr("fill", "#000")
      .text("Capacity (MB)");
});
```

I'm seeing the following error 4 times from the console:

```
Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN,NaNLNaN,NaN".
(anonymous) @ d3.v4.min.js:205
ul @ d3.v4.min.js:3768
al @ d3.v4.min.js:3775
(anonymous) @ multi-line.js:51
(anonymous) @ multi-line.js:45
(anonymous) @ d3.v4.min.js:5857
call @ d3.v4.min.js:3622
e @ d3.v4.min.js:5840
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `d3.nest`?  The example you link to doesn't use `d3.nest`.

Comment: The example that I posted doesn't use a nest, but the data relationship I'm using needs it. Here's a related [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43769353/d3-multi-level-nesting-for-multi-line-chart) that gives more information about my data.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that, but it's not 100% clear to me what you want the graph to look like. Should there be one line for each combination of storage system and pool?

Comment: I'm trying to graph out one line per pool from each storage system. For example, "system03" should have two lines for poolId "0" & "1"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The root of your problem is that the value `d` in your anonymous function passed to `dataNest.forEach` still contains one level of nesting but you are using it as if it doesn't have any nesting.  Your code fails because it is looking for `date` and `availableVolumeCapacity` properties on an object that only has `key` and `values` properties.

There are ultimately two approaches to fix this:

1. Use a single key function which combines both the storage system and pool ID.  This reduces the nesting to only one level:

   ```
   var dataNest = d3.nest()
       .key(function(d) { return d.storageSystem + " " + d.poolId; })
       .entries(data);
   ```
2. Use two nested calls to `forEach`:

   ```
   dataNest.forEach(function(d2,i2) {
       d2.forEach(function (d,i) {
           svg.append("path")
           // .... rest of inner function omitted
       });
   });
   ```

   You will need to go through all uses of `d` (in particular `d.key`) and `i` within the inner function (whose body I omitted for brevity)  to see whether you need to incorporate `d2` and `i2`.  For example, perhaps you want to use `d2.key + " " + d.key` instead of `d.key`.

Answer (score 3):

When defining your path:

```
svg.append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .style("stroke", function() {
        return d.color = z(d.key); })
    .attr("id", 'tag'+d.key.replace(/\s+/g, ''))
    .attr("d", line(d.values)); // d.values here is not defined
```

you are using what was given to you in the tutorial, but each item in `dataNest` does not have a `values` property.

Comment: Thank you @chazsolo I changed it to `.attr("d", line);` and that fixed the errors from the console. Now there is a new issue in that all of the lines on the graph overlap. It's as if they are all sharing the same data.

Comment: @Clarkus978 hmm, any chance you can get a working example on jsFiddle, or something similar?

Comment: Um, each item in `dataNest` does indeed have a `values` property. The contents of `dataNest` is in the question under 'Data Object'.

Comment: @LukeWoodward Perhaps I missed that, but it seemed the most plausible issue as `d` is what is defining the line, and he was getting NaN. If you can expose more of the issue, please feel free to explain!

Comment: @chazsolo: the questioner is using two levels of nesting (i.e. the two calls to `.key` under `d3.nest`).  Using `dataNest.forEach` unwraps one of these levels.  The error arises because the `line` function is being passed data with one level of nesting still applied, and that's not what the `x` and `y` functions are expecting.

Comment: @LukeWoodward That makes sense, thanks for the explanation! If you prefer to answer yourself I'll remove this one.

Comment: @chazsolo: I'm still not entirely sure what the questioner is trying to achieve here so I'm going to hold off answering until he/she answers my comment on the question.